# How to append NSString into NSmangedobject

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development. I want to know one thing that I am appending a string into NSmenged object it is giving me error please resolve it

Here is my code-

```
let json1 = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response.data!, options:.AllowFragments)
let json2 = json1["interests"] as! NSArray
// print(json2)
for var i=0; i<json2.count; i++
{
    let object = json2[i] as! NSDictionary
    //print(object)
    let name = object["name"] as! NSString
    print(name)
    self.names.append(name as! NSManagedObject)
}
```

In last line I am getting the error.

Comment: Please edit your question telling us what error message you are getting. It will be easier for us to analyse the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

let newContact = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: context)
newContact.setValue(txtName.text, forKey: "name")
do {
   try context.save()
} catch {
   print("Save error!")
}
```

Comment: This works !! one thing i want to know more can me make core data with unique id so that when application runs the data will not save again and again

Comment: Just check if id exist before inserting to CoreData

Comment: how to check id exist or not please tell me

Comment: retrieve all id from CoreData, check if id that you want to insert exist in CoreData, if it doesn't exsist then insert